# What is a good strategy for selling a single idea instead of a recurrent service?

Tags: attracting-clients, business-plan

Sometimes you have a good idea for making something someone might want to buy but it’s very particular and you can envision it being done maybe 1-5 times.

What is a good strategy as a freelancer for sort of pitching or advertising a kind of “suggested project”? It’s supposed to be something somebody wants, so they want to pay for it.

Comment: You can't just sell an "idea". You need to supply a complete, usable solution that implements this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Selling such is a huge challenge. In essence, you are trying to both sell someone that they need to make some change and then sell them on spending money for your efforts.

Generally speaking, something that would be a "one off" project is best done when the prospect comes up with the idea themselves and you sell them on you doing the work.

My best profit came from developing a base project that many people would want but with customizations. The customization meant that each client got a custom project, but the base meant that I could provide that solution at a tenth or twentieth the cost that other people could. (Unfortunately, the market changed, and that base became worthless. It was a great run while it lasted.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Find clients who would benefit from that service
2. Ask to meet with them to discuss your idea and how it will deliver value
3. Price your service competitively and make it "worth it" for the client
4. Demonstrate your ability to deliver based on your demonstrated skills, similar completed work, and happy former clients.

Selling a product is selling something that's already been completed. Selling a service--even a one time service--is selling something that you will do.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- - PATENT UR IDEA FIRST. Make co. sign NDA's prior to pitching idea, otherwise, you'll accidentally GIVE it away
- Market yourself as a consultant. Create pitch without giving away the idea. If Idea was a new toilet seat- pitch toilet company- "product innovation". Maybe promise to analyze their recent declined sales area and promise to deliver a product design within 3 months. Request percentage of those sales.
- Sell ur idea straight up- Online. Websites like 3m, Sharper Image or BOSCH.
- Research Angel Investors, Capital Ventures, etc. LOTS online, always looking for new money makers.
- Ask ai chat bot if its a software or app.. They help me big time.